# Black and empty desktop when switching between applications

Tags: desktop, spaces, ventura

I have a very weird bug on my professional MacBook Pro (I never encountered this bug on my other personal Mac Mini or other MacBook Pro M1).

Sometimes, When I switch from one application to another one with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, then there is a "lag" and the desktop becomes black.

[image]

The wallpaper isn't here, I can see the desktop icons but If I try to click, I am in fact the application I wanted to switch, but it is "invisible".
If I do a right click, I see a contextual menu that is part of the "invisible" application.

[image]

To fix this, I must use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> 2 times to make appear the invisible application.

Note, that this mac is very slow, and everything I do slow and laggy.

Configuration :

- Version MacBook Pro 13 inch, 2020, four Thunderbolt 3 ports
- Ventura 13.6.3

Any idea?